# How do I return a value from within a loop within a function?

Tags: c#

If I have a loop in a function, how do I return a value from within the loop?

In this example I'm using a loop to figure out if a number is prime. If I figure out the answer then I don't want the loop to continue. I just want to return it.

```
private int IsPrime (int startNumb , int endNumb)
{
    bool bilPrima = true;

    for (int i = startNumb; i<= endNumb; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i%j==0)
            {
                bilPrima = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (bilPrima)
        {
            bilPrima = true;
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a `do...while` loop instead. In your while expression, you check `bilPrima`.

Comment: What is this function supposed to return? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: your problem isn't that you cant return a value from inside a loop. There is nothing to stop you from doing that. There is a problem with your logic, this function always returns 0, if you mod a number with it's self it will always equal 0.

Answer (score 0):

If a function contains a loop, but the return value of the function can be determined before the loop has completed, you can just `return` the return value, and execution of the function will end.

So your function could look like this:

```
private bool IsPrime(int startNumb, int endNumb)
{
    for (int i = startNumb; i <= endNumb; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

One of the comments suggested that you might want to return a list of prime numbers. If that's the case then the answer would be completely different.

You could return an `IEnumerable<int>`. Within your function, create a `List<int>`. As you loop through values, every time you find a prime number add it to the list. Then at the end of the function, return the list.

You can do the same thing with `yield return` - I'm just trying not to overload you.

Comment: Thankyou, but it still can not return the value. because it can't implicitly type bool to int. what should i do?

Comment: You can change it to return an `int` instead of a`bool`, but otherwise do the same thing. It's also good to make it clearer what the function does and what it returns, even if that means giving it a longer name. The name `IsPrime` suggests that it tells you if the number is prime. It either is or isn't. So if you're returning an `int`, it's not clear what that `int` means. Also, if the function determines if a number is prime, it's unclear why there are two arguments. But all of that is a slightly different topic.

Comment: there are two arguments, because i createa program to display the prime numbers that exist in
a range of number, from a starting to an ending number. so that's why

Comment: @J.Din: if you want to return a list of prime-numbers between two numbers you should return `IEnumerable<int>`. You could even use `yield return` then to provide deferred execution and to save CPU power if the caller just needs the first (`GetPrimes(20,30).First()`).